# DAX - Create a table based on a condition

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following table `Table`

[image]

Where `Other Columns` represent multiple other columns of the large `Table`. How can I create another table that contains only rows for person `p1` and `p3` who provided a comment, and only the first 3 columns (WITHOUT other multiple columns after column `Person`? The desired output should look like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
Table 2 = 
VAR comments = CALCULATETABLE( VALUES('Table'[Person]), 'Table'[Comment] <> "") 
VAR tbl = FILTER('Table', 'Table'[Person] IN comments)
RETURN SELECTCOLUMNS( tbl, "Score", 'Table'[Score], "Comment", 'Table'[Comment], "Person", 'Table'[Person])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Table 2 = 
VAR comments = CALCULATETABLE( VALUES('Table'[Person]), 'Table'[Comment] <> "") 
VAR tbl = FILTER('Table', 'Table'[Person] = comments)
RETURN tbl
```

Comment: Thank for an easy understanding formula. However, it resulted in this error `<ccon>A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected.</ccon>` which I can't understand what "A table of multiple values" refers to.

Comment: I can't debug without a minimal reproducible example. Have you got more data to share that causes the error?

Comment: Hi David. I edited the OP with enough data to reproduce the error `<ccon>A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected.</ccon>`. Thanks

Comment: I'll add another answer for you.